# How can you console.log tab?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I would am trying to implement some functionality of the tab key. Is is possible to get it's current value/position or whatever really.

Comment: What do you mean by the value or position of the tab key?

Comment: What "functionality" are you looking for?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Do you mean you’d like to get the currently focused element?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you want to do? What do you mean by the tabs value? I think you mean the text cursor? Please add more details

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
  if (e.code ==="Tab") console.log(e)
})
```